# mount files present in a directory in docker image with the directory in the host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I have a docker image in which there are few configuration files present in the directory `/opt/app/config` now i wanted to mount this directory to a host directory so that config files can be accessed from host.

my docker compose is a follows

```
  web:
    image: web:v1
    container_name: web
    volumes:
      - ./config:/opt/app/config
    command: ["tail","-f","/dev/null"]
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

if i run the individual web image using `docker run -it web:v1 bash` and do `ls /opt/app/config` i can see the config files

but using `docker-compose up`the containers are getting created but the files are not being reflected in the host path.

when i do `ls ./config` the directory is empty. The expected behaviour is the files present in docker image at `/opt/app/config` shloud be reflected in my host `./config` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you mount a host directory into container, the contents of host directory shadow the contents of container.

If you want to access files present in container on host, you can mount a named volume as follows.

```
services:
  web:
    image: web:v1
    container_name: web
    volumes:
      - config:/opt/app/config
    command: ["tail","-f","/dev/null"]
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
volumes:
  config:
```

Then you can find the path of config volume using `docker inspect config` and see the contents from the container.

If you want to specify the path on host machine, you can specify the path of named volume in compose file as follows.

```
volumes:
  config:
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      device: /tmp/2    ------> Path on host machine
```

Comment: It worked can you explain whats happening in driver_opts

Comment: You are passing the configuration options to the volume driver. You can find more information here - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/